# Iterating through dataframes for creating and filling new data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following large dataframes:

```
Jan_Feb2019 
Mar_Apr2019 
May_Jun2019 
Jul_Aug2019 
Sep_Oct2019 
Nov_Dec2019 
Jan_Feb2020 
Mar_2020
```

And i use the following code to generate other dataframes and fill the columns with the data i want.

```
#Jan_Feb2019
Jan_Feb2019_df <- as.data.frame(Jan_Feb2019$reactions$summary$total_count)
colnames(Jan_Feb2019_df)[1] <- "Reactions"
Jan_Feb2019_df$Shares <- Jan_Feb2019$shares$count
Jan_Feb2019_df$Comments <- Jan_Feb2019$comments$summary$total_count
Jan_Feb2019_df$Message <- Jan_Feb2019$message
Jan_Feb2019_df$Likes <- Jan_Feb2019$likes$summary$total_count
Jan_Feb2019_df$CreatedDate <- Jan_Feb2019$created_time
Jan_Feb2019_df$PostID <- Jan_Feb2019$id
Jan_Feb2019_df$Love <- Jan_Feb2019$reacts_love$summary$total_count
Jan_Feb2019_df$Angry <- Jan_Feb2019$reacts_angry$summary$total_count
Jan_Feb2019_df$Sad <- Jan_Feb2019$reacts_sad$summary$total_count
Jan_Feb2019_df$HAHA <- Jan_Feb2019$reacts_haha$summary$total_count
Jan_Feb2019_df$WOW <- Jan_Feb2019$reacts_wow$summary$total_count
Jan_Feb2019_df$CreatedDate <- anytime(Jan_Feb2019_df[,6])
Jan_Feb2019_df$insights.data <- Jan_Feb2019$insights$data

Jan_Feb2019_df <- Jan_Feb2019_df %>% 
  unnest(insights.data) %>% 
  unnest(values) %>% 
  select(Message,Shares,Comments,Reactions,Likes,CreatedDate,PostID,Love,Angry,Sad,HAHA,WOW,name,value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Is there a way to iterate between all the above dataframes, so i won't have to repeat the process 8 times?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @ Ronak, unfortunately my data are confidential, but i think it does not matter, since i only care about repeating the above code. I have tried using a for loop but i'm not sure how to refer to each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is untested. I have tried to follow the code in the question, making it general. There are 2 functions.

- `fillNewDf` takes the old object as only argument and creates and fills the new data frame.
- `makeNewDf` takes the old object *name* as an argument and calls `fillNewDf` returning its value.

If the objects are in the global environment then `makeNewDf` argument `envir` default value is used.

```
fillNewDf <- function(X){
  vec <- X[['reactions']][['summary']][['total_count']]
  Y <- data.frame(Reactions = vec)
  Y[['Shares']] <- X[['shares']][['count']]
  Y[['Comments']] <- X[['comments']][['summary']][['total_count']]
  Y[['Message']] <- X[['message']]
  Y[['Likes']] <- X[['likes']][['summary']][['total_count']]
  Y[['CreatedDate']] <- X[['created_time']]
  Y[['PostID']] <- X[['id']]
  Y[['Love']] <- X[['reacts_love']][['summary']][['total_count']]
  Y[['Angry']] <- X[['reacts_angry']][['summary']][['total_count']]
  Y[['Sad']] <- X[['reacts_sad']][['summary']][['total_count']]
  Y[['HAHA']] <- X[['reacts_haha']][['summary']][['total_count']]
  Y[['WOW']] <- X[['reacts_wow']][['summary']][['total_count']]
  Y[['CreatedDate']] <- anytime(Y[, 6])
  Y[['insights.data']] <- X[['insights']][['data']]

  Y %>% 
    unnest(insights.data) %>% 
    unnest(values) %>% 
    select(Message, Shares, Comments, Reactions, Likes, CreatedDate, PostID, Love, Angry, Sad, HAHA, WOW, name, value) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
}
makeNewDf <- function(X, envir = .GlobalEnv){
  DF <- get(X, envir = envir)
  filNewDf(DF)
}
```

Now get the names of the objects to be processed with `ls()` and create a list with the new data frames.

```
old_names <- ls(pattern = '\\d{4}$')
new_list <- lapply(old_list, makeNewDf)
names(new_list) <- paste(old_names, "df", sep = "_")
```

If these new data frames are to become objects in the global environment, `list2env(new_list)` will create them with the same names as the names attribute of `new_list`.